# 100% CPU usage on 1000 connection - Node.js, socket.io, clusters and Redis ...

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, cluster-computing

My chat works on 24 Threads (2x 6 cores X5650  @ 2.67GHz) ... if there are about 1000 connections CPU usage (on every thread) grows up to 80-100% .... I think that something is wrong with my code ... node shouldn't generate such load with only 1000 connections. Can you please give me some idea about where to look

My code:

```
express     =   require('express')
http        =   require('http');
cluster     =   require("cluster");
numCPUs     =   require("os").cpus().length,
port        =   55678;
userCount   =   0;
interv      =   false;

RedisStore  =   require("socket.io/lib/stores/redis"),
redis       =   require("socket.io/node_modules/redis"),
pub         =   redis.createClient(),
sub         =   redis.createClient(),
client      =   redis.createClient(),
counter     =   redis.createClient();

counter.set('count',0);
client.set('searching',0);
client.del('freeusers');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
}
else
{
    app     =   express();
    server  =   http.createServer(app).listen(port);
    io      =   require('socket.io').listen(server);

    io.configure(function () {
        //  io.set("transports", ["websocket"])
        io.set("store", new RedisStore({
            redisPub: pub,
            redisSub: sub,
            redisClient: client
        })
        );
        io.set('log level', 0);
        io.enable('browser client minification');
        io.enable('browser client etag');
        io.enable('browser client gzip');
    });

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.php');
    });

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
        var address = socket.handshake.address;

        socket.set('options', JSON.stringify({'sex':'male','seek':'both'}));
        socket.set('partner', 5);
        socket.set('ip', address.address);

        socket.emit('setsocket',socket.id);
        counter.incr('count', function(err, newId){
            userCount = newId;

            socket.emit('people', userCount);
            socket.broadcast.emit('people', userCount);
            //  console.log(Date(Date.now()) + ' Connected User ('+socket.id+' | '+address.address+':'+address.port+') '+userCount);
        });
        socket.ip       =   address.address;

        socket.on('syscmd', function(cmd){
            switch (cmd.cmd){
                case 'new':
                socket.set('options', JSON.stringify({'sex':cmd.sex,'seek':cmd.seek}));

                socket.emit('updatechat', 'Poszukujemy dla Ciebie obcego, poczekaj ...');
                socket.emit('setflag',1);

                addNewUser(socket.id);
                lookforpartner(socket.id);
                break;
                case 'reconnect':

                socket.set('options', JSON.stringify({'sex':cmd.sex,'seek':cmd.seek}));

                socket.get('partner', function(err, partner){
                    stopchat(socket.id,partner);

                    socket.emit('updatechat', 'Poszukujemy dla Ciebie obcego, poczekaj ...');
                    socket.emit('setflag',1);

                    addNewUser(socket.id);
                    lookforpartner(socket.id);

                });
                break;
                default:
            }

        });

        socket.on('sexchange', function (sex) {
            socket.get('options',function(err,options){
                socket.set('options', JSON.stringify({'sex':sex,'seek':options.seek}));
            });
        });

        socket.on('seekchange', function (seek) {
            socket.get('options',function(err,options){
                socket.set('options', JSON.stringify({'sex':options.sex,'seek':seek}));
            });
        });

        socket.on('updatechat', function(data){
            socket.get('partner', function(err, partner) {
                io.sockets.socket(partner).emit('updatechat',data);
            });
            socket.emit('updatechat',data);
        });

        socket.on('msgchat', function (data) {
            socket.get('partner', function(err, partner) {
                io.sockets.socket(partner).emit('msgchat',socket.id,data);
                //  console.log('Message between: '+socket.id+ ' AND '+partner+': '+data);
            });
            socket.emit('msgchat',socket.id , data);
        });

        socket.on('typing', function (data) {
            socket.get('partner', function(err, partner){
                io.sockets.socket(partner).emit('typing');
            });
        });
        socket.on('stoptyping', function (data) {
            socket.get('partner', function(err, partner){
                io.sockets.socket(partner).emit('stoptyping');
            });
        });


        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            var address = socket.handshake.address;
            socket.get('partner', function(err, partner){
                stopchat(socket.id,partner)
                counter.decr('count', function(err, newId){
                    userCount = newId;

                    socket.broadcast.emit('people', userCount);
                    //      console.log(Date(Date.now()) + ' Disconnected User ('+socket.id+' | '+address.address+':'+address.port+') '+userCount);
                });
            });
        });

        function removeUser(id)
        {
            client.srem('freeusers',id);
        }

        function addNewUser(id)
        {
            removeUser(id);
            client.sadd('freeusers',id);
        }

        function lookforpartner(id)
        {
            //  console.log('('+id+') searching ...')
            client.get('searching',function(error,result){
                if(parseInt(result) == 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    client.smembers('freeusers',function(error,freeusers){
                        if(freeusers.length > 1)
                        {
                            client.set('searching',1);
                            partner = freeusers[Math.floor(Math.random()*freeusers.length)];

                            while(partner == id)
                            {
                                partner = freeusers[Math.floor(Math.random()*freeusers.length)];
                            }

                            socket.get('options',function(err,options){
                                options = JSON.parse(options);

                                if(err || options == null || typeof options != 'object' || !options.hasOwnProperty('seek') || !options.hasOwnProperty('sex'))
                                {
                                    client.set('searching',0);
                                    return false;
                                }

                                //  console.log('partner: '+id+' (sex:'+options.sex+' and seek:'+options.seek+')');

                                io.sockets.socket(partner).get('options',function(err,poptions){
                                    poptions = JSON.parse(poptions);

                                    if(err || options == null || typeof poptions != 'object' || !poptions.hasOwnProperty('seek') || !poptions.hasOwnProperty('sex'))
                                    {
                                        removeGhost(partner);
                                        client.set('searching',0);
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    //  console.log('partner: '+partner+' (sex:'+poptions.sex+' and seek:'+poptions.seek+')');

                                    if((options.seek == poptions.sex || options.seek == 'both') && (poptions.seek == options.sex || poptions.seek == 'both'))
                                    {

                                        //          console.log('parred: '+partner+' (sex:'+poptions.sex+' and seek:'+poptions.seek+') AND '+id+' (sex:'+options.sex+' and seek:'+options.seek+')');

                                        removeUser(partner);
                                        removeUser(id);

                                        io.sockets.socket(id).set('partner', partner);
                                        io.sockets.socket(partner).set('partner', id);

                                        io.sockets.socket(id).emit('chatunblock',1);
                                        io.sockets.socket(partner).emit('chatunblock',1);

                                        io.sockets.socket(id).emit('updatechat', 'Obcy podłączony, napisz Cześć :-)');
                                        io.sockets.socket(partner).emit('updatechat', 'Obcy podłączony, napisz Cześć :-)');
                                    }
                                    client.set('searching',0);
                                });
                            });


                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }

        function removeGhost(id)
        {
            console.log('Removing ghost: '+id);
            removeUser(id);
            io.sockets.socket(id).set('partner', 5);
            io.sockets.socket(id).emit('disconnected','end');
        }

        function stopchat(id,partner)
        {
            removeUser(id);

            if(partner != 5)
            {
                socket.set('partner', 5);
                io.sockets.socket(partner).set('partner', 5);
                io.sockets.socket(partner).emit('updatechat', 'Obcy wyszedł :-(');
                io.sockets.socket(partner).emit('disconnected','end');
            }
            io.sockets.socket(id).emit('disconnected',2);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: can you tell us more about how you are testing it? are the 1000 clients emitting messages to each other? are they reconnecting and thus needing FS access to get `./index.php`?

Comment: Those are real people :-) And .. they are simply talking between each other ... emiting text messages only. What do you mean "FS access" ?

Comment: FS = filesystem access, to spin up the drive when you serve `/`: `res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.php');`. But it sounds like that's not it. Neat app!

Comment: do you have some timeout set on the client side, for emitting `typing`  and `stoptying` events to limit flood? how many total messages are being exchanged, and of what types? finally, do you need to explicitly `return false` in `addNewUser` for the case where `if(freeusers.length > 1)` resolves false? (i.e. if there are 0 free users. i'm not familiar with redis so I have no idea what happens without `return`)

Comment: there is no "timeout" i just emit typing once and after user finished (message has been sent or just text in input == '') i'm calling it off with stoptyping so it's not flooding. I have no idea how many messages was exchanged and in what time ... Those are only simple text (string) messages ... usually very short ... like "hi", "how you doing" :D There is no problem with 0 free users ... if there are no users .. nothing is happening.

Comment: anyone ? :-( it's really important to me ...

Comment: Did you eventually figure it out? I am not in any way an expert but the typing stop typing events can be triggered very often I would say, maybe they consume a lot of resources. If you did figure it out I would be very interested to kow how many users your setup is holding